# How Can the `id` Query String Parameter in a Blazor WebSocket Connection Be Accessed?

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

When debugging with my Blazor server-side application, I see the following message:

```
[2022-02-25T10:40:19.177Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://<host>/_blazor?id=<_identifier_>.
```

I am interested in the `id` query string parameter specifically.  Is this value available in any way within a Blazor application?  I looked in the [`ComponentHub.Context.ConnectionId`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Components/Server/src/ComponentHub.cs#L122) but it does not appear to match this value.

I do realize that I can use the `IHttpContextAccesssor`, but want to stay away from this as this is [considered poor practice with Blazor applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-and-shared-state).

(If I am mistaken about this particular scenario that would be great to know as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an internal implementation detail of the SignalR handshake, and it is absolutely not meant for the developer to do anything with it.

For instance, if a websocket connection can't be established, because of networking issues, SignalR falls back to long polling, and each long polling request will get a new ID query parameter, which internally all map to the same  SignalR connection id.

See also this great article why this is a bad idea: https://consultwithgriff.com/signalr-connection-ids/